# Random number with modulo ARM

Tags: arm, modulo

I'm coding a guess the number game in ARM to learn more about it.
But i'm stuck at the random number generation...
I call rand() but I don't know how to do the modulo 100 to generate a number in the range 0-100.
I don't think there is modulo in ARM and "and r0, r0, #100" is not very random...

Here is the start of the pseudo random number generation :

```
mov r0, #0
bl time
bl srand
bl rand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANDs only work if the remainder you are interested in comes from the division with a power of 2. One thing you could do would be to use one such value instead of 100.

An alternative would be just to use the remainder theorem:

`a % 100 = a - (100 * int(a/100))`

This is what gcc does as well (though it avoids actually *dividing* with 100 by something called [reciprocal multiplication](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html); if your ARM supports integer divide instructions, though, you're [lucky](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABGAFJI.html)).

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try to use the remainder theorem.